# Security issue when programmatically converting 2003 .mdb to 2007 .accdb using ConvertAccessProject()

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, security, office-interop

I am currently trying to migrate an Access db from 2003 .mdb to 2007 .accdb. However, I get an error that states that I do not have the necessary permissions to do this, this is due to the security.mdw file in the same directory. Here is the code in question:

```
var newApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
newApp.ConvertAccessProject(@"C:\Users\Documents\Old.mdb", @"C:\Users\Documents\NewDB.accdb", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcFileFormat.acFileFormatAccess2007);
newApp.Quit();
```

I've tried to google this problem as well as look on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find much support/others having a similar issue.

Is it possible to convert the database using `ConvertAccessProject()` using the security file? How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I usually just open up the Access file in a 2007 + version of Access and then use the File : Save As menu option to same in a different version. When using Interop you have to be careful of the version you are using.  The version is in the interop filename.  You may need to save the new file in a different folder from old file.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have been tasked to do it programmatically althought using File : Save As would be easier if it was a single database to migrate.

Comment: I've done something similar long ago. Afair this was not trivial, and required use of the undocumented `DAO.PrivDbEngine` object and the `CompactRepair` method to do the conversion.

Comment: @ErikA could you elaborate furhter on how I could do this?

Comment: As said, long ago and the code was for a one-time thing, so I don't have it anymore. VBA has syntax highlighting for the PrivDbEngine stuff so I'd start trying to get something working there.

Comment: I am working with C#, thank you for your help regardless!

Comment: It sounds like the .mdb itself has been secured and you don't have proper permissions.  I am guessing you'll need to use Application.SetDefaultWorkgroup to join the workgroup specified by your security.mdw file and that you'll have to have a user id and pw for a user with read permissions on all the mdb objects.  Without joining the security.mdw workgroup you are by default joining the system.mdw as generic "admin" user, and if whoever secured that .mdb did their job right "admin" has very few rights if any in that db.  Can you open the .mdb directly in Access and view table records, etc?

Comment: @deluxeinformation no, I use the corresponding bat file of the access db, it then opens and asks me for the user id and password, once those are entered, i can see the database as normal.

Comment: You have a batch file that starts msaccess.exe with the /workgroup command line parameter set.  Your C# program will also need to specify the workgroup file, e.g. newApp.SetDefaultWorkgroup(path_to_security.mdw)

Comment: @deluxeinformation Thank you for your response, your response definitely helped! I am not getting an error that reads "You are trying to convert an encoded database. Decode the database, and then try again.", is there any way around this?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to decrypt it programmatically using the Application object.  You might be able to do it with Application.RunCommand acCmdEncryptDecryptDatabase but the best this might do is pop up a dialog box which would require some intervention.  You may also be able to do it using DAO, e.g. DBEngine.CompactDatabase path_to_encrypted_db, path_to_new_unencrypted_db, , dbEncrypt.  This would create an unencrypted copy of your original db.  You should also be able to unencrypt by opening in Access and doing it manually, if that's an option.